# If you cast a spell as a bonus action, can you use an action provided by some ongoing spells on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

If you cast a spell with a bonus action, you can't cast a spell with a casting time of one action (PHB, p. 202):

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven’t already taken a bonus action this turn. You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action

Does this apply to ongoing spells that provide an action after being cast?

[*Sunbeam*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sunbeam)

> A beam of brilliant light flashes out from your hand in a 5-foot-wide, 60-foot-long line. Each creature in the line must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes 6d8 radiant damage and is blinded until your next turn. On a successful save, it takes half as much damage and isn’t blinded by this spell. Undead and oozes have disadvantage on this saving throw.
>
> You can create a new line of radiance **as your action** on any turn until the spell ends.
>
> For the duration, a mote of brilliant radiance shines in your hand. It sheds bright light in a 30-foot radius and dim light for an additional 30 feet. This light is sunlight.

[*Witch Bolt*](https://dnd5e.fandom.com/wiki/Witch_Bolt)

> A beam of crackling, blue energy lances out toward a creature within range, forming a sustained arc of lightning between you and the target. Make a ranged spell attack against that creature. On a hit, the target takes 1d12 lightning damage, and on each of your turns for the duration, you can use your **action** to deal 1d12 lightning damage to the target automatically

Am I wrong an interpreting this as allowing to cast a spell as a bonus action on the same turn as the actions provided by these spells?

- Turn 1: I cast *sunbeam*
- Turn 2: I cast hunter's mark, then use the action provided by *sunbeam* to create a new beam.

Comment: Closely related: [Does re-casting Witch Bolt use up another spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137187)

Answer (score 14):

## Yes, you can continue using the spell's effect

These two spells have casting time of 1 action, which means they are cast only once, [unlike spells with longer casting time](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154135). [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/137188/36848) argues, that due to wording - which you emphasised in your question - subsequent activations are not casting (or re-casting, as linked question put it.) These actions don't have defined name (Attack, Disengage etc.) and you're allowed to take it while the spell is active.

Also worth noting that casting a bonus action spell [doesn't stop Witch Bolt from functioning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83406), unless that spell requires concentration. Examples:

- Casting [Expeditious Retreat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/expeditious-retreat) - has duration: concentration
- Readying [Misty Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) - consist of casting it in your turn and concentrating on it ([Combat - Ready action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready))
- Quickening any regular action spell that requires concentration

I couldn't find a spell that allows activating it on following turns but doesn't require concentration.

Comment: It'd probably be better to include the reasoning used in those linked questions in your answer. Answers should really stand alone and not require going to another Q&A.

Comment: Spirit Weapon would be a spell not requiring concentration that you can activate on later turns. Irrelevant to the overall point though, as activating an ability granted by a spell is not the same as casting a spell, and also because Spirit Weapon's activation is a bonus action rendering it not particularly relevant to this question.

Comment: RAW doesn't allow for readying *misty step*. "To be readied, a spell must have a casting time of 1 action [...]" 
*Find familiar* is an example of a non-concentration spell that provides action options, such as using an action to temporarily dismiss your familiar or see through its eyes. Using the extra action from *sunbeam* then casting *hunter's mark* is possible, casting *hunter's mark* ends *sunbeam* though, because they're both concentration spells, so you can't cast *hunter's mark* first.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, this works

As is suggested in the section you quoted from the PHB p. 202 "*You can’t **cast** another spell during the same turn, **except for a cantrip** with a casting time of 1 action*". The emphasis here is not being able to cast a spell. If *Witch Bolt* is already active, then you can use your action to cause damage, and still cast a spell that requires a bonus action (but no concentration).

If you cast a spell such as *Spirit Weapon* which requires a bonus action, the same process would occur. With Spirit Weapon, you can continue to use your bonus action in subsequent rounds to cause damage. In the subsequent rounds, you are not casting the spell again, therefore you can cast other spells in those rounds. It's worth remembering that **only one of the spells can require concentration**.

**Example 1** (Wizard, Sorcerer):

- round 1: cast ***Witch Bolt/Sunbeam*** (action; requires concentration)
- round 2: use ***Witch Bolt/Sunbeam*** feature (action); cast ***Misty Step*** (bonus action; does not require concentration)
- round 3: use ***Witch Bolt/Sunbeam*** feature (action)

**Example 2** (Cleric/Druid):

- round 1: cast ***Sacred Flame*** (Cantrip, action), cast ***Spiritual Weapon*** (bonus action; does not requires concentration)
- round 2: cast ***Call Lightning*** (action; requires concentration), use *Spiritual Weapon* feature (bonus action)
- round 3: use *Call Lightning* feature (action), use *Spiritual Weapon* feature (bonus action)