# If I use a bonus action to do something besides cast a spell, can I cast a non-cantrip spell with my action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, spellcasting, bonus-action

In D&D 5e, what are the rules for casting spells when using a bonus action to do something besides cast a spell?

For example, if I'm using a Cunning Action to Disengage as a bonus action, can I cast a non-cantrip spell as my action? Similarly, what if I'm concentrating on a spell that allows the caster to interact with it as a bonus action on subsequent turns (moving a flaming sphere, etc.)?

In these cases, you are not casting a spell, but you are still using a bonus action. 
The rules I've seen seem to specify what happens if a bonus action is used to cast a spell, but not for using a bonus action for something else besides casting a spell.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: The following question is related to your second question (effectively the inverse): "[If you cast a spell as a bonus action, can you use an action provided by some ongoing spells on the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163055)"

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

The **only** limit on the Cast a Spell action is that if you cast a bonus action spell you can only cast a cantrip. Other than that, you can cast any spell.