# Does triggering an effect of a spell count as casting a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

Spells like *Moonbeam*, *Flaming Sphere*, and *Call Lightning* allows you to use either an Action or a Bonus Action (depending on the spell) to trigger a specific effect on subsequent turns. Does triggering these effects count as casting a spell?

I'm fairly sure that one can't Counterspell them once it has been casted, but would it trigger the *Mage Slayer* feat, for example? (Assuming all conditions for *Mage Slayer* are met)

Comment: Highly related (dupe?): [If you cast a spell as a bonus action, can you use an action provided by some ongoing spells on the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163055/52137)

Comment: I've removed the  **Bonus** portion of this question, it expands the scope of the question beyond what we handle here. Drop into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat) if you want to chat about it or workshop making a separate question about it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov No yeah, that's fine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Casting a spell uses the 'Cast a Spell' action.

From the section 'Actions in Combat':

> When you take your action on your turn, you can take one of the actions presented here, an action you gained from your class or a special feature, or an action that you improvise.
> [...]
>
> **Cast a Spell**
> Spellcasters such as wizards and clerics, as well as many monsters, have access to spells and can use them to great effect in combat. Each spell has a casting time, which specifies whether the caster must use an action, a reaction, minutes, or even hours to cast the spell. Casting a spell is, therefore, not necessarily an action. Most spells do have a casting time of 1 action, so a spellcaster often uses his or her action in combat to cast such a spell.

You are casting a spell only when you take the **Cast a Spell** action. The actions described in those particular spell descriptions *are not* the **Cast a Spell** action, rather they are "an action you gained form a special feature".

#### *Counterspell* does not work here.

*Counterspell*'s trigger says:

> which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you **casting a spell**.

Since the actions mentioned in these spell descriptions are not "casting a spell", *counterspell* cannot be used.

#### Mage Slayer does not work here.

Similar reasoning as *counterspell*. The first point of Mage Slayer says:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you **casts a spell**

Answer (score 3):

## Not viable for *counterspell* or anything else that triggers off of 'casting a spell'

As you've stated, those continuing actions/bonus actions on an active spell are just that - continuing actions. You aren't casting a new spell and/or using components. You are just using a function of the spell.

> which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell

*Counterspell* is only a viable reaction if a creature is casting a spell. Without that specific action, there is nothing to *counterspell.* That spell is really just about attempting to stop someone from completing a casting.

If you want to stop a currently active spell, your best bet is *dispel magic* or something similar that works against currently active spells or magical effects.